# how to filter the query when an object is related to multiple categories?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to fetch the movie results that are related to two categories for 
   example the "Romance" & "Drama".. if I say something like
   `$genre->with("movie")->where("genre","Romance")->where("genre","Drama")->get();`
     Naturally it won't work so is not there any simple way to do it?

```
  <!-- my controller -->
   public function show()
      {
            $genres = new genres;
             $y = $genre->with("movie")->where("genre","Romance")->get();
             return $y;
       }
    <!-- model -->
   <?php

   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\movies;
     class genres extends Model
       {
         public $table ="genres";
         public function movie(){
             return $this->belongsToMany(movies::class,
                   "relation","genre_id","movie_id");
                                 }
       }
```

Comment: use `whereIn` would solve the problem

Comment: in is really useful in a way thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function show()
{
    $search = ['Romance'];
    // Or
    $search = ['Action', 'Romance'];

    $genres = genres::with('movie')->whereIn('genre', $search)->get();
    return $genres;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OR condition like this:

```
$genre->with("movie")->where("genre","Romance")->orWhere("genre","Drama") ->get();
```

this is equivalent to `where genre = 'Romance' OR genre = 'Drama'`

Comment: what if I want the results that share both categories then ?? to do it I imagine I have to query one category a time and then try to filter it somehow......I mean the movies that have the categories of drama and Romance?